# Website Paypal button from Facebook

Tags: facebook, paypal

I have an error that i don't understand or can troubleshoot easily.
My website has a shopping page consisting of a form and a Paypal button.

When the shopping page is the accessed from a Facebook link in a browser the button works fine, clicking submit takes you through to the Paypal checkout.

BUT if the same button is clicked from Facebook when accessed from a smart phone, i get redirected to the Paypal login page.

Not a user experience i think that works.

Any suggestions that i can research are welcome at this stage.

Comment: can you provide the link to test it?

Comment: As i said before the paypal button works in a desktop browser, and from a browser on smart phones: [web page](http://www.bringoutthebunting.co.uk/product_RWLY.html).  Where it breaks is when the same button is accessed through the Facebook page [(Facebook Link: you will have to scroll down to find a product link)](https://www.facebook.com/BringOutTheBunting?fref=ts). It should take you to a basket view in paypal, but instead you go to a login page, and after logging in the basket is not even an option!

Comment: After a little think, a quick fix would be to force the link from Facebook to open in the Safari smart phone browser. And not in the Facebook app. Any ideas on if this can be done?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Coming up against the same issue

Comment: From what i can recall, i think it was down to something as simple as changing the form target to "self"

<form target="_self" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I just had the same problem and the answer from user2004211 worked.

I changed `<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="paypal">`

To this: `<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_self">`

And it's now working in Facebook and in a proper browser.

Comment: This fixed it for me!